# Is Latching handled by the Master or Node?

Tags: ros, master, latch, publisher, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is Latching handled by the Master or Node?

Thanks,

Aaron

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137116/is-latching-handled-by-the-master-or-node?/) by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4485/unknown_entity1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2014-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since `latching` must be done on a per-connection level it is done by the publishing node when a new subscriber connects to it.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4485/unknown_entity1/) on 2014-03-07**:
That doesn't make sense in a pub/sub model. It seems to me like the Master should be handling this in the Topic Handling rather than sending new connections to a Publisher. I assumed the Publisher didn't know anything about it, and the master (server) acted as a proxy that streamed the message to whomever subscribed to the Topic.... Any idea why?